# Añadir los valores de un input en una lista en razor c# mediante un boton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un **formulario html** con un `input` de tipo date con un **botón** añadir, también tengo una lista en razor de tipo `string`.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento que haga click en añadir el valor del `input` se almacene en la lista para poder enviar esa lista como parámetro al controlador.

Esta es mi lista en razor.

```
@{
    List<string> r_fechas = new List<string>();
}
```

Este es mi formulario html.

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addFecha">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha</label>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" v-model="fecha" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" class="btn-danger" id="btnAdd" value="añadir"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

Quisiera hacer algo asi:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-danger" id="btnAdd" value="añadir" onclick="@r_fechas.Add("valor del input")"/>
```

hay alguna forma de hacerlo porque he estado averiguando y entiendo que razor corre de lado del servidor, o hay alguna forma de almacenar esos valores en una lista y luego pasarlo a un controlador que descargara un reporte pdf con las fechas de la lista que le pase.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente: dentro de tu **formulario html/razor** crear un `input` de tipo `hidden` para cada una de las fechas de tu lista, el nombre de dichos `input` de tipo `hidden` debe coincidir con el nombre de la variable en la que recibes dicha lista del lado del servidor (en tu action si estas utilizando ASP.NET MVC).

Además agregar un botón de tipo `button` no `submit` para capturar el evento en el que agregas la nueva fecha a la lista ya existente, ya sea con `jQuery` o `javascript` puro. Cuando dicho botón sea presionado agregar un nuevo `input` de tipo `hidden` a tu formulario con el valor de la fecha seleccionada. (siempre el `input hidden` debe tener el mismo nombre que los anteriores)

De forma que tendrías que tener dos botones, uno para agregar el elemento a la lista y otro para enviar el formulario hacia el servidor. Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo he hecho y me ha funcionado.

```
//Action que recibe la lista de cadenas
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<string> listaFechas)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Luego en tu vista razor tendrías algo como esto:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">
            Fecha
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" />
        </label>

        <button type="button" id="btnAgregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button> @*Boton para agregar la nueva fecha a la lista*@
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
            {
                //Aquí en vez de hacer un ciclo del uno al cinco tú harías un foreach con cada elemento del modelo que recibe la vista
                //Algo como foreach(var fecha in Model)
                //{
                //    @Html.Hidden("listaFechas", fecha);
                //}
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("listaFechas", "Fecha: " + (i + 1));
                }

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">  @*botón que envía el formulario*@
            Enviar
        </button>
    }

</div>
```

Y finalmente el código que te permite capturar el evento del botón que agrega la nueva fecha a la lista existente.

```
    <script>

    $(function () {
        $("#btnAgregar").click(function () {
            var fecha = $("#fecha").val(); //obtengo el valor de la nueva fecha a agregar.
            var hidden = "<input name='listaFechas' type='hidden' value='" + fecha + "' />" //Creo el nuevo elemento de tipo hidden
            $("#myForm").append(hidden); //Agrego el nuevo hidden al formulario.
        })
    })
</script>
```